# Identifying 6 pins SMD .0B6q9

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Trying to identify SMD component with 6 pins and code .`0B6q9`. or .`OB6q9`. on top [image]

Comment: Difficult with this picture only - please provide details about the PCB, the exact package dimensions, maybe a picture of the entire PCBA from the top and bottom. It would also be helpful to know what the 6 pins are connected to (schematic)....

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Chipown (芯朋微电子) AP3127B](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1808311811_Wuxi-Chipown-Micro-electronics-AP3127B025MR_C130343.pdf) DC/DC converter.

[image]
(source: [chipown.com.cn](https://www.chipown.com.cn/en/prodetails/140/2041.html))

Here is a picture:

[image]
(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/LED-Drivers_Wuxi-Chipown-Micro-electronics-AP3127B025MR_C130343.html))